# How to edit string in key value paring on client side. (Paypal checkout demo)

Tags: javascript, rest, api, paypal

I have a small online business where I'd like to implement an online payment system. The one that I've settled on is paypal and they have an easy to use solution found here: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client

I'm currently unclear how I can allow the end user to edit how much they'd like to pay. As it is currently, upon payment, the end user can only pay 1 cent (or however much I change the string value to. Either way the value is static). I'd like to find a solution where the end user can pay as much or as little as they'd like.

The code that paypal provides is as follows:

```
<div class='uk-section'>
            <!-- Set up a container element for the button -->
            <div id="paypal-button-container"></div>

            <!-- Include the PayPal JavaScript SDK -->
            <script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=sd=USD"></script>

            <script>
                // Render the PayPal button into #paypal-button-container
                paypal.Buttons({

                    // Set up the transaction
                    createOrder: function(data, actions) {
                        return actions.order.create({
                            purchase_units: [{
                                amount: {
                                    value: '0.01'
                                }
                            }]
                        });
                    },

                    // Finalize the transaction
                    onApprove: function(data, actions) {
                        return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
                            // Show a success message to the buyer
                            alert('Transaction completed by ' + details.payer.name.given_name + '!');
                        });
                    }


                }).render('#paypal-button-container');
            </script>
        </div>
```

As you can see the value amount is a string key pair within an object, within another object, in an array, in an object, that is an input parameter for a return statement inside a function. Any guidance into finding a working solution would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Just put your amount in a input field for the user to enter his/her value and use that to transfer over to the PayPal API..
With HTML just use an Input field for the amount for the user.
Using REST API V2 CLIENT SIDE CODE with JavaScript and a mix of Jquery

```
        // Render the PayPal button into #paypal-button-container
       // by - Using PayPal REST V2 API
       paypal
        .Buttons({


    style: {
        layout: 'horizontal',
        color: 'gold',
        shape: 'pill',
        label: 'checkout',
        size: 'responsive',
        tagline: 'true',
    },
    // Set up the transaction
    createOrder: function(data, actions) {
        $('#paypalmsg').hide();
        $('#transmsg').html('<b>'+'WAITING ON AUTHORIZATION...'+'</b>');
        $('#chkoutmsg').hide()
        return actions.order.create({
            purchase_units: [{
                description: 'GnG Order',
                amount: {
                    value: cartTotal (HERE IS WHERE YOUR USER INPUT AMOUNT WOULD GO AS 
                    A VARIABLE, you will have to make it a VAR using JavaScript or 
                    Jquery, I.E. UserVal = $(USERSelect).val();)

                }
            }],
            application_context: {
              shipping_preference: 'NO_SHIPPING'
            }

           });
       },
       // Finalize the transaction
       onApprove: function(data, actions) {
        return actions.order.get().then(function(orderDetails) {
                // Show a success message to the buyer
                $('#transmsg').html('<b>' + 'AUTHORIZED...' + '</b>');
                $('#transmsg').append('<br>'+'Transaction completed by: ' + 
                orderDetails.payer.name.given_name +' '+ 
                orderDetails.payer.name.surname + '<br>' + "Order Id: " + 
                 orderDetails.id + '<br>' + 'Status: ' + orderDetails.status+'!' + 
                '<br>'+ 'Thank You For Your Order'+ '<br>');
                if (orderDetails.status === "APPROVED") {
                    window.setTimeout(function() {}, 500)
                     $('#transmsg').append('<b>' + 'Sending Order...Please Wait' + 
                    '</b>'+'<br>');
                     // do some form clean up before the email post 
                     var getId = '#'+ $('span:contains("Market")').attr('id');
                     var getmrktDiv = '#'+ $(getId).offsetParent().attr('id');
                     var mrktchkId = '#'+ 
                     $(getmrktDiv).closest(getmrktDiv).find(".chkbox").attr('id');
                     var mrktpriceId = '#'+ 
                     $(getmrktDiv).closest(getmrktDiv).find(".price").attr('id');
                     var chkboxId = "#chk6";
                     var hidpriceId = "#pricef";
                     var marketLocation =  $(mrktchkId);
                     /* Lets do a little Validation */
                     /* This is WHERE you do any form validation (without using PayPal 
                     built-in Validation function */
                     if (marketLocation.length > 0 ) {
                       var checked = $(mrktchkId).prop('checked');
                       if (!checked) {
                         var storedVal = $(mrktpriceId).val();
                         if ($(mrktpriceId+':not([data-val])')) {
                           $(mrktpriceId).attr("data-val", storedVal);
                         }
                       $(mrktpriceId).val("");
                       }
                     }

                    $('#transid').val(orderDetails.id); (PAYPAL RETURN TRANSACTION ID, 
                                                         ADD TO FORM BEFORE POST)
                    $('#orderstat').val(orderDetails.status); (PAYPAL ORDER STATUS,
                                                         ADD TO FORM BEFORE POST)                                                                
                    $('#orderform').submit(); (SEND EMAIL TO BUSINESS EMAIL AFTER 
                                               TRANSACTION IS AUTHORIZED)
                } 
             });

             if (details.error === 'INSTRUMENT_DECLINED') {
                $('#transmsg').html('<b>' + 'TRANSACTION WAS DECLINED'+'</b>');
                $('#transmsg').fadeIn('slow').delay(3000).fadeOut('slow', function() {
                $('#paypalmsg').show();
                $('#chkoutmsg').show();
                $('#transmsg').empty();
             });

            return actions.restart();
           };
         },

         onCancel: function(data) {
            $('#transmsg').html('<b>' + 'YOUR TRANSACTION WAS CANCELLED' + '</b>');
            $('#transmsg').fadeIn('slow').delay(3000).fadeOut('slow', function() {
            $('#paypalmsg').show();
            $('#chkoutmsg').show();
            $('#transmsg').empty();
         });
       }

       }).render('#paypal-button-container');

       </script>
```

Hope this helps you get in the right direction.